# How can I delete "Passenger" from my "System Preference"?

Tags: macos, preferences, system-settings

About 2 years ago I tried and installed [Phusion Passenger Preference Pane for OS X](http://www.railsinside.com/deployment/23-phusion-passenger-preference-pane-for-os-x.html) and now I need to delete its "Passenger" icon from my System Preference. There's no uninstall option, how can I delete it?

I use Mac OS X 10.5.8

[image: My System Preference]

[image: Passenger]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just right click the icon and select remove. (it will be moved to trash which you can empty to get rid of it completely)

Comment: Oh, wow!! Wonderful! It's working! Thanks Jonathan. Really appreciate it. This very simple solution made me feel stupid for not trying to right click it :-)) d'oh!

Comment: No problem took me a while to find it myself originally.